# Horizontally stretch items with horizontal orientation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking to show a dynamic number of buttons in a horizontal way, so that they always fill up the space horizontally no matter how many items.

For example, when there are two button

```
__________________________________
| other controls                 |
|                                |
|________________________________|
| Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 |
----------------------------------
```

and button 2 gets hidden(collapsed), this should become

```
__________________________________
| other controls                 |
|                                |
|________________________________|
|    Button 1    |    Button 3   |
----------------------------------
```

Is this possible with Winrt/WP 8.1 xaml?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes, pretty much everything I could find by searching the web & SO. Horizontal stackpanel, listview with stackpanel, grids with different combinations of auto/1* columnwidths, ...

Comment: Ive tweeted it also ;) but splitpanel an option? See reference here http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tabbed_interface_with_Pivot_animation_for_Windows_Phone

Comment: @Depechie, that works to split them evenly among the horizontal space, but doesn't update when one of the items becomes collapsed.

Comment: Hmm I see, that's not ok then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would work with a Grid and set the column width to zero in order to hide it. Since all other columns have star values they should stretch accordingly. If everything fails you can recalculate the star values manually since you know the number of visible buttons.

**Sample:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Foo" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Foo" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Foo" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Set the ColumnDefinition of one column to zero and the button is hidden and the other columns adjust accordingly.

Comment: This is simple & works great. I've bound the Width to a boolean with a BooleanToGridLengthConverter to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You can always provide your own custom layout logic by deriving from `Panel`. Here's what I came up with:

**StretchPanel.cs**

```cs
class StretchPanel : Panel
{
    #region Properties

    public bool EqualWidths
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(EqualWidthsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EqualWidthsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EqualWidthsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EqualWidths", typeof(bool), typeof(StretchPanel), new PropertyMetadata(false, onEqualWidthsChanged));

    #endregion

    static void onEqualWidthsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = (StretchPanel)d;
        panel.InvalidateMeasure();
        panel.InvalidateArrange();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var renderedChildren = Children.Where(c => c.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
        var count = renderedChildren.Count();

        Size childAvailableSize = availableSize;
        if (EqualWidths)
            childAvailableSize = new Size(availableSize.Width / count, availableSize.Height);

        foreach (var child in renderedChildren)
            child.Measure(childAvailableSize);

        var totalHeight = renderedChildren.Max(c => c.DesiredSize.Height);
        return new Size(availableSize.Width, totalHeight);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var renderedChildren = Children.Where(c => c.Visibility == Visibility.Visible);
        var count = renderedChildren.Count();
        var equalWidth = finalSize.Width / count;

        var totalWidth = renderedChildren.Sum(c => c.DesiredSize.Width);
        var totalHeight = renderedChildren.Max(c => c.DesiredSize.Height);

        var x = 0.0;

        foreach (var child in renderedChildren)
        {
            var r = new Rect();
            r.X = x;
            r.Y = 0;
            r.Width = EqualWidths ? equalWidth : child.DesiredSize.Width / totalWidth * finalSize.Width;
            r.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height;

            child.Arrange(r);

            x += r.Width;
        }

        return new Size(finalSize.Width, totalHeight);
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App19.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App19"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Different widths</TextBlock>
        <local:StretchPanel EqualWidths="False">
            <Button>a</Button>
            <Button>big</Button>
            <Button>purple</Button>
            <Button>dishwasher</Button>
        </local:StretchPanel>

        <TextBlock>Equal widths</TextBlock>
        <local:StretchPanel EqualWidths="True">
            <Button>a</Button>
            <Button>big</Button>
            <Button>purple</Button>
            <Button>dishwasher</Button>
        </local:StretchPanel>

        <TextBlock>Different widths, one child hidden</TextBlock>
        <local:StretchPanel EqualWidths="False">
            <Button>a</Button>
            <Button>big</Button>
            <Button Visibility="Collapsed">purple</Button>
            <Button>dishwasher</Button>
        </local:StretchPanel>

        <TextBlock>Equal widths, one child hidden</TextBlock>
        <local:StretchPanel EqualWidths="True">
            <Button>a</Button>
            <Button>big</Button>
            <Button Visibility="Collapsed">purple</Button>
            <Button>dishwasher</Button>
        </local:StretchPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

And a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've tried something similar with the SplitPanel @depechie linked, but in my case the MeasureOverride seemed to happen when the Children still had Collapsed for Visibility.